# PFQueryTableViewController results limit?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

Is there a limit to the number of results for a PFQueryTableViewController? I know that a typical PFQuery has a default limit of 100, and I am planning to have thousands of objects, so I want to ensure that there won't be any issues with a limit to the number of results.  I was testing a PFQueryTableViewController and it was displaying hundreds of objects with no modification to the limit, but I couldn't find anything specific in the documentation regarding the differences with PFQueryTableViewController and the typical PFQuery.